# Highcharts custom symbol and colour per node

Tags: highcharts

I've been looking at this fiddle in an attempt to understand Highcharts network graphs: https://jsfiddle.net/20g58t9f/

What I'd like to do is apply a different colour/shape to each node in the graph. I'd have thought that something like this would work:

```
marker: {
  radius: 40,
  symbol: '{point.symbol}',
  fillColor: '{point.fillcolor}'
},
data:  [{
  from: {
    name: 'n1',
    rel: "myRelation",
  },
  to: 'n2',
  fillcolor: 'green',
  symbol: 'triangle'
}, {
  from: 'n2',
  to: 'n3',
  fillcolor: 'blue',
  symbol: 'square'
}];
```

It doesn't, though; each node ends up as a black circle. I can't find any information on how `point` is being used in this example, either (https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Point is of no help).
Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `nodes` options to customize individual node.

```
nodes: [{
  id: 'n2',
  color: 'yellow',
}, {
  id: 'n3',
  color: 'red',
  marker: {
    symbol: 'triangle'
  }
}, {
  id: 'n4',
  color: 'green',
  marker: {
    symbol: 'square'
  }
}]
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/etug64kw/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.networkgraph.nodes